# No way to connect to my wifi - Dell m4800 - ubuntu 13.10x64bits

Tags: wireless, 13.10, 64-bit, dell

I can't achieve to connect to my WiFi with a Dell Precision m4800 with Ubuntu 13.10 64 bits.

I added the recommended "Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Network adapter" in Software & upgrades, which allows me to see the WiFi boxes around me.

However, impossible to connect to them : the authentication always fails.

```
My lspci :
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d4)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev d4)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev d4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
```

I would be very appreciative of any kind of assistance :)

Comment: Please run `dmesg | tail -n 20` just after you have try to connect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

Since I got my M4800 I have been struggling with the exact same problem.

While I hope the next driver will simply solve everything, I did actually find something that works - at least a bit. Unfortunately it's not a permanent, but gets my Ubuntu Studio 13.10 to connect at maybe 2 of 3 logins.

I followed the recipe from this thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1783272&page=3

$ sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

Simply add:

```
blacklist mac80211
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist cfg80211
blacklist wl
blacklist lib80211_crypt_tkip
blacklist lib80211
```

Save and close. Then open:

$ sudo gedit /etc/rc.local

And BEFORE the exit 0, add:

```
sleep 2
modprobe wl
```

Save. Reboot. Chances are your wifi might connect at next login. At least in Ubuntu Studio 13.10. In Mint I can not make it work.

I hope this will be useful for someone, at least for a while.